# Records Insertion Query With SQL Database

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm using the following code in my application, but my records are not inserted. There are no errors at runtime, but there are also no records after execution completes.

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\ARIF\\Documents\\HouseTax.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

cmd.Connection = cn;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into HSTX (DATE,OW_FST_NM,OW_MDL_NM,OW_LST_NM,LD_FST_NM,LD_MDL_NM,LD_LST_NM,ADRS,LCTN_CD,HSE_DESC,ONRSHP,SQR_MTR,WRD_NO,GVT_PRO,CNST_YR)VALUES(@DATE,@OW_FST_NM,@OW_MDL_NM,@OW_LST_NM,@LD_FST_NM,@LD_MDL_NM,@LD_LST_NM,@ADRS,@LCTN_CD,@HSE_DESC,@ONRSHP,@SQR_MTR,@WRD_NO,@GVT_PRO,@CNST_YR)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", txt_dte.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OW_FST_NM", txt_onr_fstnm.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OW_MDL_NM", txt_onr_mdlnm.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OW_LST_NM", txt_onr_lstnm.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LD_FST_NM", txt_lrd_fstnm.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LD_MDL_NM", txt_lrd_mdlnm.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LD_LST_NM", txt_lrd_lstnm.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADRS", txt_adrs.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LCTN_CD", txt_lcsn_comboBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HSE_DESC", txt_hse_comboBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ONRSHP", txt_ownr_comboBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SQR_MTR", txt_sqrmtr.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WRD_NO", txt_wrd_comboBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GVT_PRO", txt_govt_comboBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNST_YR", txt_yr_comboBox6.Text);

cn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
```

Comment: I DON'T WANT TO LISTEN TO YOUR SHOUTING

Comment: What is the return value of cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()?

Comment: the result of ExecuteNonQuery might help you out some.

Comment: Have you tried running the computer manually? In like SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: sounds like you're swallowing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Ms Sql server local databases (SQLEXPRESS edition) are created in project folder (local databases). If such a case, that database is consider as a resource and it is copied at `Debug\Bin` folder by the VS. And this is what you are instructing through `AttachDbFilename` attribute value